# Multipart form uploads + memory leaks in golang?

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, go

The following server code:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  file, _, err := r.FormFile("file")
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, err)
    return
  }
  defer file.Close()

  return
}

func main() {
  http.ListenAndServe(":8081", http.HandlerFunc(handler))
}
```

being run and then calling it with:

```
curl -i -F "file=@./large-file" --form hello=world http://localhost:8081/
```

Where the `large-file` is about 80MB seems to have some form of memory leak in Go 1.4.2 on darwin/amd64 and linux/amd64.

When I hook up `pprof`, I see that `bytes.makeSlice` uses 96MB of memory after calling the service a few times (eventually called by `r.FormFile` in my code above).

If I keep calling `curl`, the memory usage of the process grow slows over time, eventually seeming to stick around 300MB on my machine.

Thoughts? I assume this isn't expected/ I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: FInding memory leaks is tricky in GCed language. Especially as the memory is not returned to the OS immediately. But I think it might be worth trying to close the Body. I just skimmed the source and didn't see an obvious close of Body.

Comment: @Volker normally the server will close the body (see [Body](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) field). I think this is just "normal" allocation behavior. Although I'm a little out of date since the switch to contiguous stacks.

Comment: 32MB default: [http.FormFile](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/4d8db00/src/net/http/request.go#L1376) ,
[defaultMaxMemory](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/4d8db00/src/net/http/request.go#L34)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the memory usage stagnates at a "maximum", I wouldn't really call that a memory leak. I would rather say the GC not being eager and being lazy. Or just don't want to physically free memory if it is frequently reallocated / needed. If it would be really a memory leak, used memory wouldn't stop at 300 MB.

`r.FormFile("file")` will result in a call to [`Request.ParseMultipartForm()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseMultipartForm), and 32 MB will be used as the value of `maxMemory` parameter (the value of `defaultMaxMemory` variable defined in `request.go`). Since you upload a larger file (80 MB), a buffer of size 32 MB at least will be created - eventually (this is implemented in [`multipart.Reader.ReadFrom()`](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#Reader.ReadForm)). Since [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) is used to read the content, the reading process will start with a small or empty buffer, and reallocate whenever a bigger is needed.

The strategy of buffer reallocations and the buffer sizes are implementation dependent (and also depends on the size of the chunks being read/decoded from the request), but just to have a rough picture, imagine it like this: 0 bytes, 4 KB, 16 KB, 64 KB, 256 KB, 1 MB, 4 MB, 16 MB, 64 MB. Again, this is just theoretical, but illustrates that the sum  can even grow beyond 100 MB just to read the first 32 MB of the file in memory at which point it will be decided that it will be moved/stored in file. See the implementation of [`multipart.Reader.ReadFrom()`](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#Reader.ReadForm) for details. This reasonably explains the 96 MB allocation.

Do this a couple of times, and without the GC releasing the allocated buffers immediately, you can easily end up with 300 MB. And if there is enough free memory, there is no pressure on the GC to hurry with releasing memory. The reason why you see it growing relatively big is because large buffers are used in the background. Would you do the same with uploading a 1MB file, you would probably not experience this.

If it is important to you, you can also call `Request.ParseMultipartForm()` manually with a smaller `maxMemory` value, e.g.

```
r.ParseMultipartForm(2 << 20) // 2 MB
file, _, err := r.FormFile("file")
// ... rest of your handler
```

Doing so much smaller (and fewer) buffers will be allocated in the background.

Comment: Thanks for this! I put my curl call in a loop and saw it capped out at 300 and would never grow beyond that. I had dismissed it as GC behavior as I tried forcing it to run, but I guess the GC doesn't always release memory even if the references have been released.